# tilde over a symbol Phi

Tags: math-mode, greek, tilde

Please suggest me a way to put tilde over a symbol phi.
I can easily put it over a letter but coming to the case of symbols, it is giving problems.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about `$\tilde{\phi}$`?

Comment: More generally: accents in math mode use different commands to accents in text mode.

Answer (score 192):

Does `\widetilde{\phi}` work for you?

If you enter this in http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php, it produces a nice Phi with Tilde.

Comment: In my case, I wanted a tilde over an M_{A}. I had to use \widetilde{M}_{A} so that the tilde is the full width of the M without extending over the subscript as well.