# How to get j where the dot in the j becomes a tilde?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How do I get a j in math mode, where the dot in the j becomes a tilde? Attached is a picture.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: `\tilde{\jmath}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [tilde over a symbol Phi](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66418/tilde-over-a-symbol-phi)

Comment: @TomBombadil I don't think it's a duplicate at all really: it's `\jmath` that is the answer here, not `\tilde` so a question about phi isn't the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `\tilde{\jmath}`, but one may argue that the `j` character is not really nice then.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$\tilde{\jmath}$
\end{document}
```

[image]