# How to add ~ on top of a greek letter

Tags: math-mode, accents, greek

How can I add `~` on top of a greek letter?

I have tried `$\~\upsilon$` for example. For hat, I used `\hat{\upsilon}` in math mode.

Comment: `$\tilde\upsilon$`? It is really hard to tell something specific with that little information.

Comment: Do you need this in regular text or mathmode only? Do you need more greek letters with accents?

Comment: May [this link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66423/101651) be useful?

Comment: I need it in math mode only. I suppose  `$\tilde\upsilon$` was what I wanted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Johannes_B suggested in the comment, it seems `\tilde\upsilon` does what I need to do in math mode.

Comment: You should ask the commentator to post the comment as an answer so that you can accept it rather than posting it an answer.